# Кто работает с Javascript на Eclipse? Подскажите пожалуйста с настройками

Tags: javascript, eclipse

Много лет веду свои проекты на СДК Eclipse. Плюс для работы с XML содержимым установлен плагин Oxygen XML Editor, а для работы с Perl плагин EPIC. В принципе СДК в такой комплектации вполне устраивал. Недавно возникла необходимость работать с Javascript. Установил модуль Eclipse WTP (Wed Tools Project) вроде как специально предназначенный для подобных целей. Поддержка Javascript у него довольно объёмно прописана в настройках и в целом кажется весьма достойной. Но вот две принципиальных вещи напрочь отказываются работать:

1. **Валидация синтаксиса** - не работает от слова "никак". Что только не пытался ковырять в настройках. Ни на какие синтаксические ошибки не реагирует - ни в on-line режиме, ни при сохранении, ни при специальном запуске validate из контекстного меню.
2. **Отображение структуры скрипта в Outline** - ну очень убогая. Видятся только переменные/константы и функции-конструкторы. Директивы добавления в прототипы методов, описания свойств (через Object.defineProperty) и прочие директивы объектов полностью игнорируются.
   [image: Типичный скрин скрипта]

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так и можно ли как-то поправить ситуацию.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Принципиально используете Eclipse? Вы пробовали [VSCodium](https://vscodium.com/)? [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/ru-ru/webstorm/) от JetBrains?

Comment: Да, использование Eclipse принципиально. Основная рабата у меня не на клиенте, а на сервере. Лучшей связки XML+Perl не встречал больше нигде. Может перешёл бы на чистый Oxygen XML Editor (а не на его Eclipse плагин как сейчас), но он не дружит с Perl.